# How do I filter a timeframe or time range in a list with dates with times?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

Here's the list

[image]

How do I create a filter for specific time ranges so it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your locale, try:

```
=filter(A:B,(mod(A:A,1)*24)>=16.9,(mod(A:A,1)*24)<=18)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, my test data was formatted AM not PM. Solution updated.